# What (or who) is the Valeyard?

Tags: doctor-who, character-identification

The Valeyard has been one of the those puzzles in Doctor Who.

Part of it is the novelization (from an older script) has the Master say "The Valeyard, Doctor, is your penultimate reincarnation... Somewhere between your twelfth and thirteenth regeneration." while the actual TV show has "amalgamation of the darker sides of [the Doctor's] nature, [taken] somewhere between [his] twelfth and final incarnation".

But if the Valeyard is supposedly a future version of the Doctor based on what we have seen since the Doctor meeting the Valeyard made this future a "fixed point in time".

Which brings us back to what is the Valeyard given thanks to the Doctor getting 13 more regenerations (I'm hoping the Timeless Child thing is the Master jerking the Doctor around)?  Also how far into the future was the Master's knowledge?

Comment: The only reference to the Valyard in televised New doctor who is by the great intelligence when he enters the time scar.  So in my opinion the Valyard is from 11's timeline where he died and Gallifrey fell and Clara was not involved and he was probably a bit more vicious even by 11 standards.  This timeline did not happen on screen as all of the attempts to kill the doctor just gave him a way to outwit them on the second version of the timeline - which was onscreen.   Note the Doctor does not die on Trenzalore and Gallifrey does not fall - but it did the first time.  Clara changed it.

Comment: https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/The_Valeyard

Comment: 'the Doctor meeting the Valeyard made this future a "fixed point in time"' — did it? Who says?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite isn't knowing what's going to happen in the future what makes something a "fixed point"? Reference: Amy & The Doctor reading River's book in _Angles take Manhattan_, also, Amy & Rory seeing their grave stones there with dates in the past. Of course, this can vary based on needs of plot, but it seems _reasonably_ consistent...

Comment: @FreeMan: ah okay, [sure](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Fixed_point_in_time), that seems kinda solid. I feel like somewhere in the new series (maybe *Partings of the Ways*?) the Doctor did say that part of being a Time Lord was perceiving possible futures all the time, so maybe foreknowledge by a Time Lord doesn't create a fixed point in the same way it could for simple life-forms like humans.

Comment: W00t!!!! I got it right and even used the same reference!! _pats self on back. hurts arm in the process_

Comment: The "Related Questions" sidebar pulled up this, which appears to be a duplicate: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/47235/21430 It's from 7 years ago, and has accrued no less than 19 answers in the meantime, most of them pretty speculative, because there are precious few canonical references to go on.

Comment: A strong theory is that the Valeyard connects somehow with the Meta-Crisis Doctor (aka Ten Two), who emerged from an aborted regeneration between the last (Eleventh) and penultimate (Tenth) incarnations of the Doctor's original regeneration cycle, and who embodied the darker elements of the Doctor's nature.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated, The Valeyard was said in the show to be "an *amalgamation* of the Doctor's darker sides from between his twelfth and final incarnations". An 'amalgamation' means to merge two things together. It does not mean halfway between two things. This suggests that he was *created* from elements of The Doctor, and isn't actually The Doctor himself. There was no suggestion in the TV series that The Doctor would regenerate into The Valeyard. It is possible that the change you describe between the original draft and the shooting script was made to make his character more mysterious and less of a problem for future writers. And with hindsight, we can see that the regeneration limit of 12 was eventually dealt with, and the regeneration from 12 to 13 (whether you count actual incarnations including the War Doctor, or use the perceived numbering system) has passed without any mention of the Valeyard.

There are stories about the Valeyard in extended media that may give him an origin story. An audio story stated that the Thirteenth Doctor had created the Valeyard while carrying out experiments to overturn the regeneration limit imposed by Rassilon, but obviously, the TV show has since contradicted that by tackling the renewal of The Doctor's regeneration cycle in an entirely different way. Although extended media mostly obeys the available TV canon, the ongoing TV show doesn't usually pay heed to the extended media.

Also worthy of note is that, in the episode *Twice Upon A Time*, the Testimony reeled off a list of names that The Doctor was known by. One of these was "the Shadow of the Valeyard", and not actually the Valeyard himself. This seems to affirm the Valeyard as someone connected to the Doctor, but not that they are the same person.

---

Regarding the 'fixed point in time' of the Doctor meeting the Valeyard - if The Valeyard isn't the Doctor, then this wouldn't apply. But *if* they were, the Doctor meeting a previous incarnation of themselves is normally said to be an 'anomaly' rather than a 'fixed point'. Fixed points in time are events that cannot be changed, such as the Eleventh Doctor's *perceived* death, or the Time War. When two or more Doctors meet, the versions taken out of their timeline leave without any memory of the event. For example, in *Day of The Doctor*, Ten was told by Eleven that he "would not retain" the memories.

But the trial was not an 'anomaly' - it was orchestrated by The Time Lords, and events on their timeline are fixed anyway. As self-appointed guardians of time, all time is observed from their perspective, and they seem to be the ones who declare things as 'fixed events'. This is evidenced by the fact The Doctor travels through time and space, visiting different periods of Earth history, but Time Lord history seems to run in parallel with The Doctor's life. An exception to this is The Time War, which became a 'time locked' event. The Time Lords made a failed attempt to break out of that time lock into the Doctor's current timeline, and later he returned to those events to change the outcome.